# Intellij keyboard shortcut increase editor tab splits

Tags: intellij-idea

What is the keyboard shortcut to increase/decrease the size of code tabs? Under window->active tool window->resize-> works on structure/project/etc but actual tabs with code it doesn't work.

Is is possible to increase/decrease vertically or horizontally split editor tabs?

Comment: This is now possible, you have to assign a shortcut to it. Go to settings -> keymap -> search for 'Stretch Editor to....' options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had previously misunderstood your question and now I realised you are talking about resizing only the Splitter.

This is unfortunately not possible in the moment using the keyboard, only the mouse. There is a [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-67379) for this improvement though.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend using the [Tab Shifter plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7475-tab-shifter/). You can install it from IDE:

Ctrl + Alt + S --> Plugins --> Marketplace

Type: "Tab Shifter"

The default shortcuts to resize tabs/splits:

> ctrl+alt+[ - stretch split left
>
> ctrl+alt+] - stretch split right

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In 2020.2 you can select stretch Stretch Editor to the Left / Right and assign a shortcut to this command.